# Compact flat orientable 3 manifolds and mapping tori

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lattices

There are 10 compact flat 3 manifolds up to diffeomorphism, 6 orientable and 4 non orientable. I am looking to better understand how to construct the orientable ones.

The six orientable ones are determined by their holonomy groups
$$
C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,C_6
$$
and
$$
C_2 \times C_2
$$
The five with cyclic holonomy all arise as the mapping torus of a mapping class of $ T^2 $ with the corresponding order: 1,2,3,4, or 6. These five Euclidean manifolds with cyclic holonomy can even be constructed as a quotient of the special Euclidean group $ SE_2 $ by a cocompact lattice constructed as the semidirect product of a lattice in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ and a finite cyclic subgroup of $ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ preserving that lattice. For example $ C_1 $ corresponds to the three torus $ T^3 $.

**I am very curious about the compact flat orientable 3 manifold with holonomy $ C_2 \times C_2 $ (known as the Hantzsche-Wendt manifold). It is not a mapping torus of $ T^2 $ like the other five, but perhaps it is a mapping torus of the Klein bottle $ K $?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remaining orientable manifold is called the Hantzsche-Wendt manifold $M^{HW}$, and is not a mapping torus over the Klein bottle. It has first homology $H_1(M^{HW}, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. Any mapping torus $MT(M, f)$ of a manifold $M$ via the map $f: M \to M$ has $\pi_1(MT(M, f)) \cong \pi_1(M_0) \rtimes_{f_*} \mathbb{Z}$. Abelianizing and using Hurewicz's theorem yields that if $M$ is a mapping torus of the Klein bottle, $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ must be of the form $\mathbb{Z} \times H$, where $H$ is a quotient of $H_1(K, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, and hence cannot be $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. It is worth mentioning that the $3$-torus is a normal covering space of all flat compact $3$-manifolds.

The Hantzsche-Wendt Manifold has a nice description as a branched cover of the complement of the Borromean rings, which is described in Zimmerman's paper *[On the Hantzsche-Wendt Manifold](https://eudml.org/doc/178505)*. The standard reference for a classification of compact flat 3-manifolds is J. Wolf's book *Spaces of Constant Curvature,* which gives a classification of them and explicit constructions as quotients of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by isometries.

A resource to develop visual intuition about these manifolds is Jeffrey Weeks' program [Curved Spaces](https://www.geometrygames.org/), which simulates how it would look to "fly around inside of" manifolds and has a number of flat 3 manifolds as pre-built examples, including the Hantzsche-Wendt manifold.

Comment: I seem to remember that the Hantzsche--Wendt manifold also has a nice description as the result of gluing together two twisted interval bundles over the Klein bottle.

Comment: I know of a description of the Hantzsche-Wendt manifold as two cubes with appropriate face identifications, e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.12172.pdf table 1. I'm not aware of a description of it as a gluing of twisted interval bundles over Klein bottles (but am not an expert on this sort of thing at all).

Comment: The wikipedia page for Seifert fiber space says " {b; (n3, 2); }   (b is 0 or 1) The other two non-orientable Euclidean Klein bottle bundles. The one with b = 1 is homeomorphic to {0; (n1, 1); (2, 1), (2, 1)}. The first homology is Z+Z/2Z+Z/2Z if b=0, and Z+Z/4Z if b=1. These two Klein bottle bundle are surface bundles associated to the y-homeomorphism and the product of this and the twist." Do you have any idea what this claim about Klein bottle bundles might refer to? Or is it just a case of wikipedia being wrong?

Comment: Also I understand that $ H_1 $ of the mapping torus must be a quotient of $ \mathbb{Z} \times H_1(K,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 \times C_2 $ but could you explain why the abelianization must in particular be $ \mathbb{Z} $ times a quotient of $  H_1(K,\mathbb{Z}) $?

Comment: On the Abelianization: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35713/abelianization-of-a-semidirect-product.

Comment: Seems that the answer about Klein bottle bundles I linked to has since been deleted and the answer was incorrect. I've removed that paragraph. As you mention, the wikipedia article on Seifert-Fibered spaces gives a description of all the non-orientable flat compact 3-manifolds as fiber bundles over the Klein bottle.

Comment: This is a very nice answer to the first part of my question, about the orientable case. So I'll go ahead and take out the second part of my question, about the non-orientable case, and accept this answer. Maybe I'll repost the second part as a separate question later.